# Hide ACF option sub-menu item

Tags: wordpress, hide, advanced-custom-fields, submenu

I created an ACF option menu item with sub-menu items, but I'd like to hide a specific sub-menu item (translations).

[image]

I've tried a few thing like for example:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'acf-options-translations' );
}
```

But that doesn't work. Is it possible to achieve what I need via action, or I need to go with some sketchy CSS ?

Tks

Comment: Did you tried https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/remove-options-page-submenu-item/

Comment: Thank you, but is not exactly the same problem.